# Error in zip_internal(zipfile, files, recurse, compression_level, append = FALSE, : Some files do not exist

Tags: r, path, zip, xlsx, openxlsx

Received this error message from R when using openxlsx package, not sure where to look.

> Error in zip_internal(zipfile, files, recurse, compression_level, append = FALSE,  : 
>     Some files do not exist

Does anyone have any suggestions? thanks.

The code is simple:

```
library(openxlsx)
df1 <- cars
write.xlsx(df1, file = 'cars.xlsx')
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Refence to github isse: https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/478

Answer (score 0):

The error resolves itself if you add a TMP environment variable. As I suspected this is because the `saveWorkbook` function uses the function `tempdir` which creates a temporary directory and uses the `TMP` variable (among a list of other options) to do this (see documentation for more info).

The relevant lines of code are on line 223 [here](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/blob/master/R/WorkbookClass.R). Note that `tempdir` is not called directly, but through the function `tempfile` which uses `tempdir()` as default value for its `tmpdir` argument.

Related [Github issue](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/478)